# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in firebase on next js

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I am using firebase in next js but it gives an error message as

****TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined****
Any  way how i can  fix this error.

Here is my  firebase config file

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore'
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyD0Kz7iRs6WKSXO6Iw2hEeDFeRcDGERmV8",
  authDomain: "facebook-clone-1870b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "facebook-clone-1870b",
  storageBucket: "facebook-clone-1870b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "924586129038",
  appId: "1:924586129038:web:1d4204813a4956bd353bdf"
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
    ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export  {db,storage};
```

Here is error message

```
.next\server\pages\index.js (12:13) @ Object../firebasec.js

  10 | };
  11 | 
> 12 | const app = !firebase.apps.length
     |             ^
  13 |     ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  14 |     : firebase.app();
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^9.1.3",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.7",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.17"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Firebase on `package.json` ?

Comment: firebase version is 9.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your code has **firebase v8** while you have **firebase v9** package and it has completely different import structures. This happen lot when you follow some tutorials with v8 and install firebase so it get latest version on default that's v9

What should you do:

1- Remove current version

`npm rm firebase`

2- install latest of 8.x

`npm install firebase@8.9`

Comment: @Jeevan you're welcome, accepting and voting up answer would nice