# Next.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I'm new to Next.js. Im following a youtube tutorial to build facebook using - next.js, nexauth and firebase as database. I did `npm install firebase`, created a firebase.js file.

firebase.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage";
import firebase from "firebase";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<mykey>",
  authDomain: "<domain>",
  projectId: "<projectId>",
  storageBucket: "<storageBucket>",
  messagingSenderId: "<messagingSenderId>",
  appId: "<appId>"
};

if(!firebase.apps.length){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

// Initialize Firebase
const db = app.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, storage };
```

In the `inputbox.js` where the user can write posts. On submitting the post, it will create a new collection named posts in the database and add the information by the user. But after pressing enter the page says

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

I've imported everything required for this.

InputBox.js

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/client";
import { EmojiHappyIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { CameraIcon, VideoCameraIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import { useRef } from "react";

//imports for db
import { db } from "../firebase";
import firebase from "../firebase";

function InputBox(){

    const [session] = useSession();
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const sendPost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!inputRef.current.value) return;

        //error
        db.collection('posts').add({
            message: inputRef.current.value,
            name: session.user.name,
            image: session.user.image,
            email: session.user.email,
            // timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="bg-white rounded-2xl p-2 shadow-md text-gray-500 font-medium mt-6">
            <div className="flex space-x-4 p-4 items-center">
                <Image 
                    className="rounded-full"
                    src={session.user.image}
                    width={40}
                    height={40}
                    layout="fixed"
                />

                {/* Inputbox */}

                <form className="flex flex-1">
                    <input 
                        className="rounded-full h-12 bg-gray-100 flex-grow px-5 focus:outline-none" 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder={`What's on your mind, ${session.user.name}`}
                        ref={inputRef}
                        ></input>
                    <button hidden onClick={sendPost} type="submit" >Post</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default InputBox;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in firebase on next js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684799/cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-in-firebase-on-next-js)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lottt!  I was looking for this for about 3 days.